# Django Picture link between model and Link

Tags: django

I'm working on a pet store app for fun. How my app works is , it display a page listing all the pets store and when you click on a pet store . You see all the animals in the pet store.

The problem is, I don't know how I can pass a picture from a model into a template without doing it statically I'm sorry if this doesn't make sense.

Example. When someone views the store . He will see all the animals e.g name ,description and picture.

I can upload images to my admin but how can I render the context with the picture into my template

```
 image = models.FileField(upload_to="images/")
```

My models.

```
from django.db import models

class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    number = models.BigIntegerField()
    address =models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Pet(models.Model):
    animal = models.CharField(max_length =20)
    description = models.TextField()
    owner = models.ManyToManyField(Store)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="images/")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.animal
```

My views.py

```
from pet.models import Store , Pet
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response ,get_object_or_404

def index(request):
    store = Store.objects.all()
    return render_to_response ('store.html',{'store':store})

def brazil(request , animal_id):
    pet = get_object_or_404(Pet, pk=animal_id)
    return render_to_response ('animal.html',{'pet':pet})
```

My store.html

```
Sydney's Pet Store
{% if store %}
<ul>
    {% for a in store %}
    <li><a href ="{% url world:brazil a.id %}">{{ a.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}

</ul>
{% endif %}
```

My animal.html

```
{% if store %}
<li>Pet = {{ store.animal }}</li>
<li>description = {{store.description}} </li>
<li>owner = {{ store.owner }} </li>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: If this question doesn't make sense , i'll delete it

Comment: try <img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{pet.image}}">

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FileField`s (and by extension `ImageField`s) have a `url` property you can use to get the url. You can use this property from your templates like this `<img src="{{ pet.image.url }}">`

Comment: Do people normally use this method?

Comment: Yes, that would be the normal way to do it. The url property is quite smart about things, if you use a different storage plugin (for example to store files on Amazon S3) it should handle that fine without any changes.